# Is it possible to receive a collection of data from a JSP to a struts action

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm writing a Struts 2 based web application where I want the user to paste in a list of IDs that will then be processed on the server. So I currently have a text box to accommodate that. Is there a way I can receive that data as a Collection in my bean rather than a String?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Define your action property as a collection.

Comment: Does it have to be formatted in a particular way for Struts to parse it then?

Comment: You mean you want to use single input for that? Then it is more complicated... because you still need to post it like `ids=1&ids=2`.

Comment: Use js or parse a string in the server side.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many html elements with the same value on the name attribute, they'll be received by the Struts action as a collection.

Also on your Struts action, you must have a collection whose name is the same as the value of the name attribute of these html elements.

If you want to use a single text area, you should use JavaScript to parse its content and load each element on a hidden element. Each hidden element should have the same name.

Comment: Having multiple inputs would make it hard to paste in the ids. Is it possible to do this with just a textarea?

Answer (score 0):

If you use textbox or textarea then you should place a delimiter to separate tokens. Then on the server after submit you can `split` them by delimiter to array. Then you can create a collection from the array.